# table() displaying multiple instances of the same levels in R

Tags: r

When I use the `table()` in R to get a count table of the levels of my categorical variable Description, I see multiple instances of the same distinct levels.  For example, Market Basket being a level, is shown several times below:

[image]

Do you know I can make R display exactly one count for each level?

Comment: Very likely values contains blank spaces: for instance, it seems that you have `MARKET BASKET` and `MARKET BASKET_` (I used the underscore to denote a blank space). R interpreters the two values as different. Just trim the spaces in your values (see the `?trimws` function).

Comment: For future reference, please don't post images of textual output. It is quite simple to copy/paste text to the question (prepending 4 spaces for code-formatting).

Comment: @Nicola thanks for the feedback.  You may be right.  I checked the Description column and I saw that Market Basket is alignment differently in some cases:

Comment: Trim your Description column with e.g. `stringr::str_trim()`, possibly combined with `stringr::str_to_lower()`, should help.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got what you are suggesting.  If trimmed the strings, i would need to combine the column with the rest of the data frame somehow.  I think it would be easier i could just align the column names and their values, given that the column width is uniform.  Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: The following code does what I wanted: december_expenses2[,"Description"] = trimws(december_expenses2$Description), without having to combine columns as I mentioned earlier.  Now, Market Basket show as one distinct level!  Thanks again guys.